# Tracking objects in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]
[image]

So the first picture is my original picture. After converting it from BGR to HSV, I remove the greens from the picture and the result is my 2nd picture. So, with a little bit of fine tuning I can remove the non-player objects.

My question is how do I track the players. How do I extract players from the image? I'd like to track each player across all frames.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Kalman Filter.

[Kalman Filter OpenCv](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d6a/classcv_1_1KalmanFilter.html#gsc.tab=0)

Answer (score 1):

There are many different approaches existing in OpenCV that you can just plug and play. http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/tracking/doc/tracking.html

There's also a ready-made algorithm example in [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/OpenCV_Python/python_opencv3_mean_shift_tracking_segmentation.php) with all the explanations you need and I guess it would fit your use case(football) as well.